# Как определить тип введённого значения в python?

Tags: python, типы

Надо сделать так, чтобы программа определяла, является ли введённое значение целым числом.

```
b = input('Введите первое слагаемое: ')
c = input('Введите второе слагаемое: ')

if type(b) == int and type(c) == int:
    print('Сумма равна:', b + c)      
else:
    print('Ошибка! Нужно вводить только целые числа.')
```

Всегда выдаёт 'Ошибка! Нужно вводить только целые числа.', то же самое если вместо `type` использовать `isinstance`:

```
if isinstance(b, int) and isinstance(c, int):
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот так:

```py
b = input('Введите первое слагаемое: ')
c = input('Введите второе слагаемое: ')

try:
    b = int(b)
    c = int(c)
except ValueError:
    print('Ошибка! Нужно вводить только целые числа.')
else:
    print('Сумма равна:', b + c)
```

Когда вы вызываете `input`, возвращается строка. Но мы пытаемся перевести его в число и если возникает `ValueError`, то есть не получается перевести, мы выводим нужное сообщение, и программа завершается.
Если ошибки нет, пройдет блок `else`, и все посчитается.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy поправил, теперь все работает. Спасибо за замечание!